# Get list of objects from a list of ids javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, find

I have a list of objects that say look something like this:

```
const fruit = [
     {
          name: 'banana',
          id: 1
     },
     {
          name: 'apple',
          id: 8
     },
     {
          name: 'orange',
          id: 3
     }
];
```

And I have a list of Ids:

```
const ids = [8, 1];
```

And I'm looking to grab all the "fruit" that have an id in my list of ids, i.e. I want my result to look like:

```
const result = [
     {
          name: 'apple',
          id: 8
     },
     {
          name: 'banana',
          id: 1
     }
]
```

I have a "working" solution where I basically go:

```
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i += 1) {
     const foundFruit = fruit.find(x => x.id === ids[i]);
     result.push(foundFruit);
}
```

But ultimately I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way to do this, as in my real example, my list of fruit can potentially be thousands of fruit long, and I could similarly ALSO have a huge list of ids.

Would this approach be the best or is there a more efficient way of mapping these results?

Comment: sure, just do `fruitMap = new Map(fruit.map(f => [f.id, f]))` and then `result = ids.map(id => fruitMap.get(id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all fruits by their `id` and map the collected ids.

```js
const
    fruits = [{ name: 'banana', id: 1 }, { name: 'apple', id: 8 }, { name: 'orange', id: 3 }],
    ids = [8, 1],
    fruitsById = {};

for (const fruit of fruits) fruitsById[fruit.id] = fruit;

const result = ids.map(id => fruitsById[id]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in a more performant way by "hashing" the `id`s then only filtering them by lookup, like so:

```js
const fruit = [
     {
          name: 'banana',
          id: 1
     },
     {
          name: 'apple',
          id: 8
     },
     {
          name: 'orange',
          id: 3
     }
];

const ids = [8, 1];

const result = fruit.filter(function (value) {
// return this.delete(value.id); // or use this return for unique ids
  return this.has(value.id);
}, new Set(ids));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `id` property in the objects are unique, if that's the case then the following solution is better one.

I transformed the array of objects to an object with the keys of the `id` properties so the lookup for the ids becomes efficient.

```js
const fruit = [
     {
          name: 'banana',
          id: 1
     },
     {
          name: 'apple',
          id: 8
     },
     {
          name: 'orange',
          id: 3
     }
];

var fruitsObj = {};

fruit.forEach(function (o) {
  fruitsObj[o.id] = o.name;
});

const ids = [8, 1];

var result = [];

ids.forEach(function (x){
  if (fruitsObj[x]) {
    result.push({name: fruitsObj[x], id: x});
  }
});

console.log(result);
```